# can't cancel python build in sublime3 using virtualenv

Tags: python, sublimetext3, virtualenv

I can't cancel a build in python in Sublime Text 3. I tried canceling using the default and custom key bindings, and even using the command pallet.

I'm using a virtual environment via virtualenv. That seems to be the only difference between my current development platform and other ones I've been using.

***Default(windows).sublime-keymap - User:***

I tried using all of these, I know the last one was a stretch. None worked

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+b"], "command": "exec", "args": {"kill": true} },
    // { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+z"], "command": "build" }
    { "keys": ["alt+b"], "command": "cancel_build" },
    { "keys": ["alt+b"], "command": "Build: Cancel" }
]
```

***Using the command prompt:***
[image: Command]

***Without virtualenv:***

Using the default python build, without the python environment, seems to work

[image: working without virtualenv]

so i'm pretty confident it has something to do with virtualenv